# Can you romance anyone in Hogwarts Legacy?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I'm wondering if I'm able to get my flirt on with someone from Hogwarts.

Is it possible to have a romantic relationship with anyone in Hogwarts Legacy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

While you can form platonic relationships and deepen friendships with schoolmates in Hogwarts Legacy, you cannot indulge in any romance.

This was a conscious decision not to include romance options in Hogwarts Legacy from Avalanche Software (the game’s developers). The developers stated it in an interview with [GamePro](https://www.gamepro.de/artikel/hogwarts-legacy-romanzen,3389199.html). So it's unlikely we'll ever see this coming to the game in a future update.